Only the Hydrogen ions bonded to oxygen are replaceable in Phosphorous acid. Why?
The basicity of Phosphorous acid is 2 though it has 3 Hydrogen ions. I heard that it is because only the hydrogen ions bonded to Oxygen (Only 2 H ions) are replaceable. Why is it so?

You must have heard of polar bonds, right?

It involves the bond structure and the transition state for the proton transfer. The P-H bond is very covalent and the transition state for proton transfer must necessarily require considerable P-H bond breaking to be compensated with bond formation to the oxygen. Altho thermodynamically favored the high activation energy because of significant P-H bond breaking retards the reaction. To the contrary the polar O-H bond immediately forms a bond to the OH- oxygen quickly forming a low energy transition state with almost equal bonding of the proton to both O atoms Altho the O-H bond is strong the high polarity makes the proton readily transferred because the proton is easily attracted to both O atoms in the transition state. The effect is most noted in water because of the balance and the strong acids because of the more polar[and possibly weaker in HI] bond. Weak acids involve a less polar O-H bond with an increasingly unbalanced transition state in the proton transfer.

The P-H bond in H3PO3 is not the same as in the PH4 cation (we compare species with the same valence pn phosphorus). In H3PO3 the unprotonated oxygen imparts back-bonding which effectively couples the P-H bond with strong P=O pi bonding. That ties the P-H hydrogen down both thermodynamically and kinetically.
